# VHDL nonresolved signal has multiple sources

Tags: vhdl

Good day or night to you! I'm currently facing a challenge while working on the design of this fundamental fire alarm system. Here are the specific details:

The configuration comprises 2 inputs and 5 outputs. The inputs are identified as follows:
F: fire sensor
T: Activator

The outputs are labeled as:
Y: gas
I: sparker
A: Alarm
BL: blue led
YL: Yellow led

Here are the actions linked to the inputs and outputs:
When F is set: the yellow led is turned on
When F is cleared: the yellow led is turned off
When T is cleared: there is no action, and the blue led remains off
When T is set: it triggers the following tasks and activates the blue led:

Mode 1 - Normal:
Upon T activation and after a delay of Td, I and Y are activated. Upon detecting a signal from F, output I is deactivated. In this mode, A is deactivated, and F is monitored for a duration of Tv.

Mode 2 - Lock:
Upon T activation and after a delay of Td, I and Y are activated. If during the monitoring time of Tv, F's signal is not detected, the system switches to lock mode. When Tv ends, I and Y are deactivated, and A is activated.

Mode 3 - Simulation:
If the controller detects F before I and Y (during Td), it enters this mode, which means the controller won't initiate the task until F is cleared."

down below is my very beginner-level code which you can see :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity FireAlarm is
    Port (
        clk, reset, F, T : in STD_LOGIC;
        YL, BL, A, I : out STD_LOGIC;
        mode : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0)
    );
end FireAlarm;

architecture Behavioral of FireAlarm is
    type State is (Idle, Normal, Lock, Simulation);
    signal current_state, next_state : State;
    signal timer_count : integer := 0;
    constant Td : integer := 100;  -- Delay for T in clock cycles
    constant Tv : integer := 200;  -- Check time for F in clock cycles

begin

    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            current_state <= Idle;
            timer_count <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            current_state <= next_state;

            if timer_count > 0 then
                timer_count <= timer_count - 1;
            end if;

            -- Update timer_count in the synchronous process
            case current_state is
                when Normal | Lock =>
                    if timer_count > 0 then
                        timer_count <= timer_count - 1;
                    end if;
                when others =>
                    -- No need to update timer_count for other states
                    null;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(F, T, current_state)
    begin
        mode <= (others => '0');  -- Initialize mode vector

        case current_state is
            when Idle =>
                if T = '1' and F = '0' then
                    next_state <= Normal;
                    timer_count <= Td;
                else
                    next_state <= Idle;
                end if;

            when Normal =>
                YL <= '1';
                BL <= '1';
                I <= '1';

                if T = '0' and F = '1' then
                    I <= '0';
                    timer_count <= Tv;
                    next_state <= Idle;
                else
                    next_state <= Normal;
                end if;

            when Lock =>
                YL <= '0';
                BL <= '0';
                A <= '1';
                I <= '0';

                if T = '0' and F = '1' then
                    timer_count <= Tv;
                    next_state <= Idle;
                else
                    next_state <= Lock;
                end if;

            when Simulation =>
                YL <= '0';
                BL <= '0';
                A <= '0';
                I <= '0';

                if T = '1' and F = '0' then
                    next_state <= Normal;
                    timer_count <= Td;
                else
                    next_state <= Simulation;
                end if;

            when others =>
                next_state <= Idle;
        end case;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

here is the error I get using ALTERA MODELSIM 2012:

```
Error: C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Firealarm v1/main.vhd(17): Nonresolved signal 'timer_count' has multiple sources.
  Drivers:
    C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Firealarm v1/main.vhd(23):Process line__23
       Driven at:
          C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Firealarm v1/main.vhd(27)
    C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Firealarm v1/main.vhd(48):Process line__48
       Driven at:
          C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Firealarm v1/main.vhd(56)
** Error: C:/Users/user/Desktop/work/Firealarm v1/main.vhd(105): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

I have tried to research the errors, but I couldn't find anything I could do about it with my current level of understanding (which is low in this case). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are driving signal `timer_count` from multiple processes.  If one process drives the value N, and the other process drives the value M, what value should the signal take? Remember that signals are like wires on a circuit board, not like variables in a programming language.

Comment: Assign timer_count in only one process.  IEEE Std 1076-1993 12.6.1 Drivers "Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of drivers for certain scalar signals. There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S or denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement. ..."

Comment: 4.3.1.2 Signal declarations "A signal may have one or more *sources*. For a signal of a scalar type,each source is either a driver (see 12.6.1) or an **out**, **inout**, **buffer**, or **linkage** port of a component instance or of a block statement with which the signal is associated. ... It is an error if, after the elaboration of a description, a signal has multiple sources and it is not a resolved signal. ..."

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the basic issue is that the signal is driven by two separate processes. Now, it is possible to have multiple processes inside of one architecture, but each signal can only be assigned from one of them, at most. In the first process, there is a comment, "No need to update timer_count for other states." However, it seems like that is not the case, as down below, it is assigned different values based on the current_state. I would probably move the assignments to timer_count into the first, recreating the conditions which need to be met in order to perform said assignment.

Comment: Signals of a resolved type may be driven from multiple processes. When such a situation occurs, the resolution function is called. For example, type `std_logic` is declared `std_logic is resolved std_ulogic;` where `resolved` is the resolution function that determines what value results when multiple drivers occur. Synthesis tools generally do not allow multiply driven signals as their technology does not allow it. But it is definitely a VHDL feature, and is used by some verification frameworks for various tasks.